# host key verification error in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have a jenkins project that uses the ssh-agent module to use my personal key... to ssh into a remote box and run some commands. 
I've added my personal id / key information to the global "jenkins" scope or user??
(basically, i go to Home page, Credentials, clicked on the "add credentials" to the "jenkins" object listed... and then added my key information).

The build includes the following shell command:

```
ssh -t -t root@10.1.2.3 lua /var/www/widgets/test_widget.lua
```

On my dev server (running ubuntu), this project works.  It logs into the remote server, runs the above command and displays the results.

On my production server, I get the following error:

```
 Host key verification failed.
```

**What I 've Tried**

1. made sure the project on the dev box and production box are configured exactly the same way.
2. made sure my key has been entered properly in production , aka the same way as on dev
3. i manually logged into the jenkins server... and then from there I tried to ssh into the 10.1.2.3 box and I don't get any errors.
4. on the jenkins server's known_hosts file, I removed the 10.1.2.3 entry and retried... but the build still fails.
5. Made sure the production server has the same ssh plug ins installed as my dev server.

I'm not sure what else to try.

**EDIT**

I found an interesting artifact on the actual jenkins server:

```
jenkins-server1:~# ssh-keyscan 10.1.2.3 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
# 10.1.2.3 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8p1-hpn14v4
```

So I edit the file using vim and save changes.
And then I retry the scan and the entry is still there!  So it's not a problem with Jenkins... but something with that file itself.